# Cytoscape.js cxtmenu doesn't fire event on entry select

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

When I use the cxtmenu extension for Cytoscape.cs, the context menu doesn't fire its event immediately after I select an option but only after I select another node. How can I have it fire the event immediately after selecting the option? My plan is to offer way finding similar to Google Maps, where a source node is already selected and the context menu on right click on a node offers "route to here".
I use jquery 3.1.0 (only because it is stated as a requirement for cxtmenu), cytoscape.js 2.75 and the newest cytoscape-cxtmenu.
See the minimal working example for the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script><!--2.7.5-->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu/master/cytoscape-cxtmenu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"></div>
<script>
var cy = cytoscape({
 container: document.getElementById('cy'),
 elements:
 [
  {data: {id: 'n1'}},
  {data: {id: 'n2'}},
 ]
 });

var added = false;

 var defaults = {
   menuRadius: 100, // the radius of the circular menu in pixels
   selector: 'node', // elements matching this Cytoscape.js selector will trigger cxtmenus
   commands: [
   {
    content: 'test',
    select: function(node)
    {
     if(!added)
     {
     console.log('adding edge');
     cy.add({group:"edges", data: {id: 'e1', source: 'n1', target: 'n2'}});
     added=true;
    }
    }
   },
   ],
   openMenuEvents: 'cxttap', // cytoscape events that will open the menu (space separated)
 };

var cxtmenuApi = cy.cxtmenu(defaults);

var selectedNode;

cy.on('select',"node",function(event) {selectedNode = event.cyTarget;});

</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

P.S.: I managed to get an event to fire directly by using `openMenuEvents: 'cxttapstart taphold'` but then the menu activates on releasing the mouse press that intitially activated the menu.

Comment: Please file bug reports in the issue tracker.

Comment: @maxkfranz I am not sure whether that is a bug.

Comment: The extension demo page is working fine on the latest version.  I guess you could be setting `openMenuEvents` erroneously -- but it looks like you have other things in play in your case as well.